# Does Spark Application Master always run in the master node of EMR cluster or not

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have a EMR cluster (1 master node 1 core node) and I submitted my spark-application deploy mode is `cluster` mode.

From the documentation, I know the `driver` runs inside `Spark Application Master` given this deploy mode, but which node (master or core) will be selected by `Yarn` to run `Spark Application Master`?
Is it always `master` node?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Application Master never runs on the master instance of the cluster (other than an edge case where you are running a single node "cluster" with no core instances at all).

The Application Master runs on a random core/task instance of the cluster. It runs in a YARN container, so it must run on an instance that is running the YARN NodeManager. The master instance runs the YARN ResourceManager, and the core/task instances run YARN NodeManager.

Also, the driver does not always run inside the Application Master process. In fact, by default (meaning "client" deploy-mode) it does *not* run inside the Application Master process. In this case, the driver (running on the master instance) and the Application Master (running on a random core/task instance) are two completely separate things.

If you run Spark in "cluster" deploy-mode (e.g., by adding `--deploy-mode cluster` to the `spark-submit` args), then and only then will the driver run inside of the Application Master, and it will be on a random core/task instance. The only thing running on the master instance in this case will be a thin wrapper process that polls the status of the application running in YARN.